# Coding an XML document with python?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am currently taking part in a Cyber Challenge, however I have beeen asked to produce an xml file which contains nodes and atributes:

```
Generate a valid xml file at /tmp/vulnerable-countries.xml.
It should contain a list of country nodes attached to a root node
that have name attributes, the third node should be Panama.
```

I have looked everywhere for information on this and I cam up with the following.
However, after submitting this code I get the following:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element("root")
ET.SubElement(root, "Country")
ET.SubElement(root, "Country")
ET.SubElement(root, "Panama")
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("/tmp/vulnerable-countries.xml")
```

Format of /tmp/vulnerable-countries.xml was not correct. It should contain 3 country nodes with name attributes, with the third being Panama.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates that you need to include an attribute called `name` for each of your `country` nodes. Try this:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element("root")
ET.SubElement(root, "country", name="Narnia")
ET.SubElement(root, "country", name="Wakanda")
ET.SubElement(root, "country", name="Panama")
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("/tmp/vulnerable-countries.xml")
```

Result:

```xml
<root><country name="Narnia" /><country name="Wakanda" /><country name="Panama" /></root>
```

Comment: 10/10 Thank you very much, this worked and helps me to understand XML!